# How do I insert last_insert_id using preparedStatement?

Tags: java, mysql

I am facing difficulty in inserting " last_insert_id" in my prepared statement.I got how to select the last_insert_id in prepared statement like below:

```
PreparedStatement getLastInsertId = con.prepareStatement("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
```

When I use the same procedure for inserting last_insert_id in my preparedstatement   like this:

```
1.  PreparedStatement pst =  con.prepareStatement("insert into introducer_table  values(?,?,?,?)");
2.     
3.     //introducer details into database
4.       pst.setString(1,LAST_INSERT_ID());
5.     pst.setString(2, nameofintroducer);
6.     pst.setString(3, accountno);
7.     pst.setString(4, signofintroducer);
```

Im getting **'null'** value in the first column.can any one help me to come out from this problem

Comment: What LAST_INSERT_ID() method return

Comment: actually I had one table newuser it is containing two fields sid,name

Comment: when I insert sid,name in the newuser table,that sid value must be inserted in the sid column of my introducer_table.And this sid can be obtained by using last_insert_id()@nikas tyagi.

Comment: @balasrilakshmi Besides that the original problem, You have a serious issue that your `sid` should not be  a `nullable` column since you are telling that it's allowing `null`. Or I read something wrong ?

Comment: You mean to say first sid and name column value will be inserted in newuser table and it is havind primary key sid which is foreign key of introducer_table.sid which is primary key is return by using last_insert_id correct

Comment: @niks tyagi ya you are right exactly.

Comment: @suresh no,no you are mistaken,I mean to say first sid and name column value will be inserted in newuser table and it is having primary key sid which is foreign key of introducer_table.sid which is primary key is return by using last_insert_id.but im getting error instead of sid value in my introducer_table.This is my problem.

Comment: @balasrilakshmi That's exactly what I mean. That's your original problem. But what I'm trying to convey is `introducer_table.sid`  should be a `not null` column in DB design. So that It should throw a error at DB level while trying to insert a new record with `null`. Right now it allowing null also which is little scary. Hope that clears :)

Comment: @suresh to make sid column not null shall I need to take sid as primary key in my introducer_table???

Comment: @balasrilakshmi Well that's a very broad. Depends on your requirement. Do you allow to create a `introducer_table` record without a `new_user`? If yes then your sid column may have null value. If it no just make that column not `null`, making sense ?

Comment: @suresh as you said,when I execute the query given by@Bhusan,I first insert the record in newuser table,sid value '1'is generated as result,then I insert values into the introducer_table im getting sid value as 0 and remaining column values are coming as usual?what is the problem?can you help me?I also make sid column as not null in my introducer_table.but im not getting.

Comment: @balasrilakshmi I added my answer. Please check it. Hope that helps a little :). YOu just print that generated and see weather it's getting correct or not. If yes, declare it on top and use it further.

Answer (score 1):

If your doing both the save actions at a time use `getGeneratedKeys()`, It's pretty much java.

I'm not  a SQL guru, but here I found a way to get the generated id using  `getGeneratedKeys()`

```
    long generatedId= 0L;
    statement = con
            .getConnection()
            .prepareStatement(
                    "insert into  new_user set name= ? , contact= ? , ....",
                    statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    statement.setString(1, "examplename");
    statement.setString(2, "examplecontact");
    ------
    statement.executeUpdate();
    ResultSet generatedKeys = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
    if (generatedKeys.next()) {
        generatedId = generatedKeys.getLong(1);// here is your generated Id , use it to  insert in your introducer_table
    }

     PreparedStatement pst =  con.prepareStatement("insert into introducer_table  values(?,?,?,?)");

         //introducer details into database
         pst.setString(1, generatedId);
         pst.setString(2, nameofintroducer);
         pst.setString(3, accountno);
         pst.setString(4, signofintroducer);
```

Comment: @suresh but according to your query your inserting the data in the newuser table?its generating some id and that id must used in the introducer_table?is it right?

Comment: Yes exactly.. You can use it further in  insert query of `introducer_table`. That is what you want right ?

Comment: ya right but how can I add that in my introducer_table?

Comment: @suresh thanks,but the problem is the newuser related java code is in one class(named:newuser.java),and introducer_table related jdbc code is in one class(named:introducer.java).then how can I do this?pls explain me...